# Why do I get an EJS syntax error when trying to print strings from an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am developing my first real web application and am currently doing so using Node, Express and MongoDB. All data in my database follows the pattern `{question: String, learningDate: Date}`. I want to create a page to which the questions are printed under their respective dates. For example, if two questions have the same date value, they should both be printed under the one and same date. In an attempt to achieve this, I have written the code found below.

When I run the application I am faced with the following error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; in /path/to/file/views/home.ejs while compiling ejs"

I have tried playing around with the code for a while now, but cannot figure out what is causing the issue? Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this error, or otherwise, suggestions on how I could approach achieving my desired functionality differently?

**app.js** (https://pastebin.com/bhZdcNzJ)

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/review1");

const reviewSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        question: String,
        learningDate: Date
    }
)

const Review = mongoose.model("Review", reviewSchema);

app.get("/", function(req, res)
{
    Review.find({}, function(err, reviews)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log("Something went wrong.");
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            res.render("home", {reviews: reviews});
        }
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function()
{
    console.log("Active Recall server is listening on port 3000.")
});
```

**home.ejs** (https://pastebin.com/e0bN20Yz)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="author" content="Konrad M. L. Claesson"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-sacle=1"/>
    <title>Active Recall</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Active Recall</h1>

    <%
    const days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

    function formatDate(date)
    {
        var day = days[date.getDay()];
        var month = months[date.getMonth()];
        var dd = date.getDate();
        var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
        return day + ", " + dd + " " + month + " " + yyyy;
    }
    %>

    <%
    function getReviewDate(learningDate, reviewNumber)
    {
        const reviewSpace = 2 * (Math.pow(2, reviewNumber) - 1) - reviewNumber;
        let date = new Date();
        date.setDate(learningDate.getDate() + reviewSpace);
        return date;
    }
    %>

    <% function getReviewsByDate(reviews, learningDate) %>
    <% { %>
        <% let reviewsOnDate = []; %>
        <% learningDate = learningDate.valueOf(); %>
        <% reviews.forEach(function(reivew) %>
        <% { %>
            <% if (review.learningDate.valueOf() === learningDate) %>
            <% { %>
                <% reviewsOnDate.push(review); %>
            <% } %>
        <% }); %>
    <% } %>

    <%
    function removeReviewsByDate(reivews, learningDate)
    {
        reviews.forEach(function(reivew)
        {
            if (review.learningDate.valueOf() === learningDate)
            {
                let i = reviews.indexOf(review);
                reviews.splice(i, 1);
            }
        });
    }
    %>

    <% for (let i = reviews.length - 1; i > -1; i--) { %>
        <% let learningDate = reviews[i].learningDate; %>
        <% let reviewsOnDate = getReviewsByDate(reviews, learningDate); %>
        <% removeReviewsByDate(reviews, learningDate); %>

        <% for (let reviewNumber = 1; reviewNumber < 11; reviewNumber++) %>
        <% { %>
            <h4> <%= formatDate(getReviewDate(learningDate, reviewNumber)) %> </h4>
            <% reviewsOnDate.forEach(function(review) %>
            <% { %>
                <li> <%= review.question %> </li>
            <% }); %>
        <% } %>
    <% } %>
</body>
</html>
```

When I rewrite the code in "home.ejs" from scratch, I notice that the following code produces my error:

```
<% function getReviewsByDate(reviews, learningDate) %>
<% { %>
    <% let reviewsOnDate = []; %>
    <% learningDate = learningDate.valueOf(); %>
    <% reviews.forEach(function(reivew) %>
    <% { %>
        <% if (review.learningDate.valueOf() === learningDate) %>
        <% { %>
            <% reviewsOnDate.push(review); %>
        <% } %>
    <% }); %>
<% } %>
```

*Update 1*
Rewriting the excerpted code from "home.ejs" to the below code solves the syntax error.

```
<% 
function getReviewsByDate(reviews, learningDate)
{
    let reviewsOnDate = [];
    learningDate = learningDate.valueOf();
    reviews.forEach(function(reivew)
    {
        if (review.learningDate.valueOf() === learningDate)
        {
            reviewsOnDate.push(review);
        }
    });
} 
%>
```

Nevertheless, the same syntax error message returns when the below code is re-included in "home.ejs":

```
<% for (let i = reviews.length - 1; i > -1; i--) { %>
    <% let learningDate = reviews[i].learningDate; %>
    <% let reviewsOnDate = getReviewsByDate(reviews, learningDate); %>
    <% removeReviewsByDate(reviews, learningDate); %>

    <% for (let reviewNumber = 1; reviewNumber < 11; reviewNumber++) %>
    <% { %>
        <h4> <%= formatDate(getReviewDate(learningDate, reviewNumber)) %> </h4>
        <% reviewsOnDate.forEach(function(review) %>
        <% { %>
            <li> <%= review.question %> </li>
        <% }); %>
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: You are mixing `JavaScript` and `EJS` together. Just put your `JavaScript` code in between `script` tags and use `EJS` to write your data (passed through by the `express route`) on the page (`templating`). It is best practice to seperate those things as much as possible.

Comment: @Tarabass That's an odd way of saying that; EJS is JS-based templating. I don't see anything here that implies it's client-side JS, although it certainly might have been intended to be.

Comment: Unrelated, but `getReviewsByDate` doesn't appear to return anything, but you try to use its return value.

Comment: @Tarabass Could you provide a simple example of how to separate the JavaScript and EJS code? Initially, I tried to import much of my JavaScript code via script tags, but this gave me reference exceptions.

Comment: @DaveNewton That's a mistake. `getReviewsByDate` should return `reviewsOnDate`.

Comment: @K.Claesson You need to identify which JS you want to run on the server, and which to run on the client. I only see server code here, which shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: As Dave mentioned you can put the functions in your app.js (=running it serverside). Format your reviews as you like and send that formatted list of values to the client. On the client you only have one foreach to iterate over your reviews.

You can also move your javascript functions to the head of your home.ejs. This will run the code clientside but seperate it from your body.

Oh, and reviews is several times misspelled..

Comment: @Tarabass I'm not sure what you're getting at here. This code appears to be entirely server-side-related, manipulating the `reviews` from the DB. I agree most of that should be removed from the template since that's not where it belongs, but it's also not *technically* invalid to put the code there--you should be able to run arbitrary server-side JS in EJS, no?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe replace

```
<h4> <%= formatDate(getReviewDate(learningDate, reviewNumber)) %> </h4>
```

with

```
<h4> <%- formatDate(getReviewDate(learningDate, reviewNumber)) %> </h4>
```